# How to calculate this limit without De L'Hopital?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to resolve this limit without using De L'Hopital rule:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2^{x+1}-2}{x}
$$
With the rule i get ln(4).

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can note that $$2^{x+1}-2=2\cdot2^x-2=2\left(2^x-1\right)=2\cdot\left(2^x-2^0\right).$$ Hence: $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2^{x+1}-2}x=2\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2^x-2^0}{x-0}=2\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\left[2^x\right]_{x=0}$$

Answer (score 1):

This is the derivative of $2^{x+1}$ at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$2=e^{\ln2}\implies 2^x=e^{x\ln2}$$  and $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^h-1}h=1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{l}
 f\left( x \right) = 2^{x + 1}  = e^{\left( {x + 1} \right)\ln 2}  \\ 
 f'\left( 0 \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{e^{\left( {x + 1} \right)\ln 2}  - 2}}{{x - 0}} = 2\ln 2 \\ 
 \end{array}$$